# Overloading method names in categories for NSManagedObjects gives a warning in Xcode 4.4 and above

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data, categories

I have a category for each of my `NSManagedObject` subclasses, where factory methods sit, so that they are not lost when automatically regenerating the class files. So that I don't need to know what subclass of `NSManagedObject` I'm using at runtime, each subclass has the same name for its factory method, e.g.

```
+ (id)objectWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
```

(For clarity, in this example suppose there is an entity deriving from `NSManagedObject` called `Item`, with generated files Item.m and Item.h, and my own category with files Item+Factory.m and Item+Factory.h, where the method above resides).

In Xcode 4.3 this generates no warning: but Xcode 4.4 (and above flag it as a warning:

> (null): Meta method 'objectWithInfo:inManagedObjectContext:' in
>   category from ...Item+Factory.o conflicts with same method from
>   another category

Now, I'm well aware of the dangers of overloading a method in a category, it's a Bad Thing. What I'm doing here, however, is simply treating objects as a more general class than they are, which as fas as I'm aware is sensible.

Is what I'm doing bad? Or is there a different way to declare my methods to remove the warning?

Comment: Also it's bad form to add a category method to a class that you don't own without prefixing it (as a namespace) because the original vendor or library vendors can potentially add this method and cause a conflict.

Comment: It makes a new object and returns it, based on the info in the dictionary. So for each subclass of NSManagedObject I have, each implementation of this method is different. Do you mean add this method as a cat to NSMO and then implement in each sub cat?

Comment: Re: prefixes, yes I prefix but removed for privacy.

Comment: Scrap that, is there any kind of find or create logic or is it a straight creation convenience method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I was redeclaring the method in the header of each subclass. Declaring once in the superclass sorted it.

Additionally, moving all +Factory.h #imports into the precompiled header (and removing elsewhere) vastly reduces confusion and additional warnings.

Thanks to Paul.s for making me think along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably generalise that method to work in the same way for all objects

```
+ (id)ps_insertNewObjectForEntityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context objectInfo:(NSDictionary *)objectInfo;
{
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [objectInfo enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        [managedObject setValue:obj forKey:key];
    }];

    return managedObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you found this on your own, but to clarify for future readers:

Since you're adding functionality to NSManagedObject that all your subclasses need to overload, the best approach would probably be to create a general subclass of NSManagedObject that can then function as a superclass for things like Item. (Subclassing is designed to work that way, but categories aren't.) For example:

```
// ABCManagedObject.h
@interface ABCManagedObject : NSManagedObject
+ (id)objectWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
@end

// ABCManagedObject.m
@implementation ABCManagedObject
+ (id)objectWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    // no-op; use subclasses instead.
}
@end

// Item.h
@interface Item : ABCManagedObject
@end

// Item.m
@implementation Item
+ (id)objectWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    // create and initialize new object and return it
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Actually, I already do this, I just skipped that stage out my explanation. I have MYManagedObject and it has a Factory category, where I first declare these common methods. Then each subclass is of that, and has its own factory category. I think your solution implies putting the methods in the main class, not a category? But then I get back to the problem of the auto generated files...

Comment: What's the problem you're running into with the generated files? If it's just that the method doesn't show up in those files, you just need to add it to the .m file, and it'll replace the superclass's implementation. You can start typing "+ (id)objectWith...", and autocomplete should recognize it from the superclass header. (Just make sure the .h file is getting #imported.)

Comment: My problem is that I want to be able to re-autogenerate without having to make any changes, which is why the use of categories.